# Android: Return to home screen

Tags: android, homescreen

I have the following scenario: -

App loads, an intitial password logon screen appears. Once the user is logged on, they are then taken to a second screen. If they hit the back button on the second screen, I use the following code to take them to the home page of the device: -

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startActivity(intent);
```

The issue is that when I start the app again, it starts from this second screen. I want it to start from the logon screen again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`finish()` your second activity just right before going to Home.

```
    finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call `finish()` on the second activity? You don't need to redirect the user to the HOME screen by callind `startActivity()`. If your first (login) activity started the second activity and called `finish()` on itself, then there is only one activity (the second activity) in your activity stack. If you call `finish()` on that one, there isn't anything left in your activity stack and your application will just end.

The extra code to redirect the user to the HOME screen is not needed.